# Converting Array and copying it into a List

Tags: java, arraylist, enums, java-8

To be clear I don't have any problems and don't really need help but I wanted to ask anyway:

Let's say we have a String array

```
String[] sarr = new String[]{"POTATO", "TOMATO"};
```

and we have an enum

```
public enum Food{POTATO, TOMATO, PIZZA}
```

If I wanted to check if all Strings in `sarr` are present in `Food`, I'd do the following:

```
ArrayList<String> foodstrings = new ArrayList<>();
Arrays.asList(Food.values()).forEach((in) -> foodstrings.add(in.toString()));
if (!foodstrings.containsAll(Arrays.asList(sarr))) doStuff();
```

Is there a way to do this in less lines of code? Or simply a more elegant way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe a better version of the first two lines would be:

```
Set<String> foodstrings = Arrays.stream(Food.values()).map(Enum::name).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Using `Set` instead of `List` will improve performance of `containsAll`, and the code is entirely streamed, instead of using `forEach` and an external collector.

The `if` is still good, although you could just combine it all into a single statement (formatted for readability):

```
if (! Arrays.stream(Food.values())
            .map(Enum::name)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet())
            .containsAll(Arrays.asList(sarr))) {
    doStuff();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! In the end I went with your answer but Tunaki's answer was very helpful as well.

Answer (score 6):

You want to determine if all element in your array are contained in the list of food names.

A possible solution is to convert the food names to a `Set` (to have a O(1) `contains`); then, we need to determine if all elements in the array are contained in this set:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] sarr = new String[]{"POTATO", "TOMATO"};
    Set<String> set = Arrays.stream(Food.values()).map(Enum::name).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    boolean result = Arrays.stream(sarr).allMatch(set::contains);
}
```

---

In your current solution, you are mutating an external variable with `forEach`, which is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Stream.of(sarr).allMatch(s -> Stream.of(Food.values()).anyMatch(t -> s.equals(t.name()))))
{ 
    // all match
}
```

1. Create a stream out of `sarr` (which could be any `Collection` of objects amenable to the `Stream` API introduced in Java 1.8)
2. We ask for the value `allMatch`, which only returns `true` if a `Predicate` (i.e. a function that returns true/false).
3. For the `Predicate` expected by `allMatch`, we provide a lambda that iterates over a second set of objects via a stream, and calls `anyMatch`: a simple `Predicate` that will return true if any member object satisfies a provided condition (once again, a boolean function).
4. We provide yet another lambda to `anyMatch` which compares members of the 2 collections via their `equals` implementations.

This solution is semantically equivalent to the invariant

`A \subset B`

which in our case is

`sarr \subset Food.values()`

and the following Java < 1.8 code shown below with short-circuiting to mimic the specification (minus the streams overhead):

```
// assume success, since if both sets are empty the invariant holds
boolean subset = true; 

for (String a : sarr)
{
  if (null == a) continue;
  boolean contained = false;

  for (Food b : Food.values()) 
    if (b.name().equals(a)) { contained = true; break; }

  if (!contained) { subset = false; break; }
}

if (subset)
{
   // all match
}
```

You could, of course, substitute different collection types and conditions, as well as use `parallelStream()` to make better use of the hardware available.